# Powershell script to add Content Types

Tags: powershell, 2007

Very new to Powershell 1.0 on Sharepoint 2007.  I've got a site collection with many subsites.  These subsites all have a document library called Reviews.  What I need to do is add a new content type to every Reviews document library in this collection.  It sounds like this is very doable in Powershell.

I did see [this](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/11/add-and-remove-site-content-types-from.html) script, but it looks as if it's geared towards 2010.  Any pointers on adapting this to 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curse of once you post a question to something you've been working on all day you find/fix it has risen.

After looking over information and reading the error output from the linked script and referencing some other blog content, I found that if I changed the line to $site.AllWebs | ForEach-Object {, it worked, even though it threw a small error at me.